# R ggplot facet label position between y axis title and y axis tick mark labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, position, facet

I would like to put the facet labels on the left side all the way to the left so that the y-axis title is to the right of it. I can already create a suitable spacing, but I can't swap the order.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
tg <- ToothGrowth %>%
  as_tibble()

tg %>%
  ggplot(aes(supp, len)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = supp)) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(1, "cm")) +
  facet_grid(dose ~ ., switch = "y")
```

[image]

This order is important because I am putting this figure together with two others to have a more consistent layout. Thanks!!

EDIT: The best solution for me was the second link in aosmith's comment.

Here is the code:

```
tg %>%
  ggplot(aes(supp, len)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = supp)) +
  facet_grid(dose ~ ., switch = "y") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(1, "cm"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = -15))
```

[image]

The solution with the grid package also looks good, but it is complicated to continue working with it.
The solution with the fake axis changes the spacing of the x-axis tick marks
and "label = " does not accept expressions.
Thanks to all for the great help!

Comment: I saw one (complicated!) approach in [this similar SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60091106/ggplot-placing-facet-strips-above-axis-title). A couple of other approaches shown for [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009107/is-there-a-way-of-plotting-the-facet-strip-names-switched-y-outside-the-y-axis).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible natively in ggplot because of the way the finished `gtable` is laid out. The y axis label always sits to the left of the facet strips. Of course, you can render the ggplot and swap the gtable around as per the link shared by aosmith. This is probably a bit too complicated for what you want to do.

I think the simplest way to achieve the result you want is to simply draw the y axis label on to the plot once it has drawn using `grid.draw`.

```r
tg %>%
  ggplot(aes(supp, len)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = supp)) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(1, "cm"),) +
  labs(y = "") +
  facet_grid(dose ~ ., switch = "y") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") 

library(grid)

grid.draw(textGrob("len", x = unit(0.1, "npc"), y = unit(0.53, "npc"), rot = 90))
```

[image]

An alternative if you want a single `ggplot` object without having to draw over it is to make a fake axis title using `geom_text`. This will require a bit more work, but the end result is more self-contained, in that it can be passed around as an object and it can have various modifications made to it without having to always draw the label on afterwards:

```r
tg %>%
  ggplot(aes(supp, len)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = supp)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) formatC(x, width = 10)) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(1, "cm"),) +
  labs(y = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("white", "black", "white"),
                     guide = guide_none()) +
  geom_text(aes(x = -0.5, y = 20, color = factor(dose), label = "len"),
            check_overlap = TRUE, angle = 90) +
  facet_grid(dose ~ ., switch = "y") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = c(0.5, 2.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! Considering that it is a non-native solution, it seems to be feasible with relatively little additional effort. I will try it out directly with my data. Thanks again!

Comment: @maRvin you might need to play around with the numbers in the `unit` calls inside the call to `textGrob` to position the axis label appropriately. If you need to change the font face, color, etc, you can do that using a parameter called `gp` inside `textGrob` that takes as an argument a call to `grid::gpar` -  see `?grid::gpar`

Comment: Yes, increasing `x = unit(0.1, "npc")` to `x = unit(0.11, "npc")` added the spacing needed for the supercript number. :)

Comment: grid.draw does not seem to be compatible with ggsave. Is there an alternative in the grid package that is compatible? Or do you have to save the plot differently (e.g., with png())?

Comment: @maRvin see my update which gives a pure ggplot solution that will work with ggsave